# How to check the duplication of the extended version of the paper?

Tags: journals, conference, plagiarism, self-plagiarism, extended-paper

One of my papers was accepted by the conference. I now want to write an extended version of the paper for submission to the journal.

The journal requirements are:

> Extended versions of published conference papers are welcome, but
> they must have at least 40% new impacting technical/scientific
> material in the submitted journal version, and there should be less
> than 30% verbatim similarity as reported by a tool (such as CrossRef).
> Additionally, the conference papers and the detailed summary of
> differences must be included as part of the journal submission to TC.

Why can't I find the tool CrossRef?
I want to use some other websites to check the duplication, but how can I check the duplication only compared to my conference papers?

Has anyone experienced something like this? what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tool referred to is the *[CrossRef Similarity Check](https://www.crossref.org/services/similarity-check/)*. Only "CrossRef members" (i.e., mainly publishers) have access to it once they pay a special fee in return. In other words, the tool is not publicly available to you.

As regards a duplication-check you could conduct on our own, there are free text-comparison tools like [this one](https://www.copyscape.com/compare.php) where you can insert the two articles and see to which extent they overlap or differ from each other.

Here is an example (with a 68% match):

[image: the text on the left differs slightly from the text on the right]

However, note that every text-comparison tool could spit out different results, simply because [there is more than one way to calculate text similarities](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6297/how-can-we-compare-in-terms-of-similarity-two-pieces-of-text).